# How to save request body in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, export-to-csv

I am fetching data from the CSV file and giving as input to my Request.How can I save all the request in the same file when I run a test for an hour.

One more requirement is, if the result is success then I have to write that data I have used from the CSV into another file so that we can have only the data which is working in an separate file.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be using JMeter's built-in [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   sample_variables=foo
2. Replace `foo` with the variable name you're getting from the CSV file
3. Next time you [run your JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.csv
   ```

   your `result.csv` file will have an extra column called `foo` and having the `foo` variable value for each and every request. You will be also able to determine which data caused the failure by looking into "success" column

   [image: JMeter Result File Sample Variables]

Comment: Many Thanks Dmriti.....If in the response we have XML format can we extract one particular element.
For example we have two XML elements in the response like <userName>abc</userName> <pwd>def</pwd>.....Can we fetch pwd element to that output CSV file...Please suggest

Comment: yep, just separate them by commas like `sample_variables=foo,foo1`

Comment: Many Thanks Dmriti.....If in the response we have XML format can we extract one particular element. For example we have two XML elements in the response like <userName>abc</userName> <pwd>def</pwd>.....Can we fetch pwd element to that output CSV file...Please suggest

Comment: It is possible with [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) which allows executing arbitrary [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) queries against the response. I would suggest starting another thread and providing the full response and indicate which value you are interested in.