# JMeter: Save Request Body to a file

Tags: jmeter, http-post, export-to-csv

I have already seen a response from [How to save request body in Jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51174075/how-to-save-request-body-in-jmeter) but it doesnt solve.

I want to save to csv a dynamic request body constructed  e.g. {"transfer":${id},"amount":${amount}}. I want the actual request data {"transfer":1234,"amount":5678} to be in saved to a csv file. I have multi-thread running at least 50 users in parallel, so I want the file not to be created again and save all request data sent out.

Why I need is because, when I run for several users the application responds differently, and we want to compare the data(request data, response headers, response body) for different run

Best.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways of doing this:

1. Add next lines to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter):

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
   jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
   ```

   this way JMeter will store request bodies into .jtl results file
2. Alternatively you can add a Listener like [Simple Data Writer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) and configure it as follows:

   [image]
3. If you don't want XML and would like to have a plain text file take a look at [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer)

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to find out Test data specific Response times. Try this

1. Simply append the Request data in the Sampler Name as below. In the report, you can see Response times specific to your data.
   Note: Not suitable for larger data set, as it will increase number of transactions
   [image]
2. For larger data set, you can simply add logic to distinguish between ranges, as below
   [image]

[image]